# Woocommerce API POST/PUT product

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce

I just red thru the WooCommerce REST API http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce/rest-api/. Is it not possible to create products in the WooCommerce onlineshop using just the REST API?

Thx for your answer.

Cheers, Robin

Comment: You can create product in REST api . I have already created product and update order using C#

Comment: Do you have more information on that?

Comment: It works on POST and PUT operation if you have https enable in Woocommerce site

Comment: Is there any more information on the official WooCommerce page?

Answer (score 0):

No, the API in WooCommerce 2.1 is read-only. The API will be updated writes in the next version of WooCommerce (version 2.2). This version of WooCommerce is still under development and there is not set time for the release unfortunately.

If you are interested, you can follow the development of this here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues?labels=API&milestone=22&page=1

Comment: I have done code which perform create , DELETE operation in Woocommerce product.